# yeoman and gulp server won't run

Tags: node.js, gulp, yeoman

I face a problem on starting gulp server
my project files is scaffolded from webapp using yeoman

error message

```
 Requiring external module babel-register
 Using gulpfile ~/workspace/yo/gulpfile.babel.js
 Task 'server' is not in your gulpfile
```

I tried to uninstall yemoan, gulp and webapp and reinstalling them again, but the same erorr showing to me.

I tried to npm install
and npm install --save-dev babel-core.

and nothing change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error message, it looks like you're using the wrong task name. The task `server` does not exist, it's been deprecated and is now replaced by a task called `serve`. Try running `gulp serve` in the root of your project, that should fix your problem. I would also recommend looking at your gulpfile so that you could see all of the tasks that are created by Yeoman.

Comment: you are right I miss spelling, thanks!
can you help me to get rid of - Failed to load external module babel-register
, Requiring external module babel-core/register

thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I could try but I need to see the error message.

Comment: `Requiring external module babel-register
 Using gulpfile ~/workspace/yo/gulpfile.babel.js`

Comment: There's no error it's supposed to do that. Does the server work?

Comment: Yes its working, but is that an error?

Comment: Nope it's just gulp telling you that it's using an external module to do the task. If the server works you're good to go. Also please go on GitHub and read the documentation for gulp and Yeoman. It'll help you a lot.

Comment: I did, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I looked around and it seems like you're not the only one with this error. There was an [issue on Github](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/356) but it's been closed, so it's fixed in the newest version. Here's what you can do:

- The first thing you should try is update your generator, I know you just installed but still try.
- If the issue persists try looking in your `package.json` and make sure `babbel-core` is listed as a dev dependency.
- If it's not then add it and run `npm install` in the root of your project.
- If it is in the `package.json` still try running `npm install` in the root of your directory.

You should see `babbel-core` in the `node_modules` directory. If it's not there then just install it manually, follow instructions in the `README.md` [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-core). (hint: run the installer command in the `node_modules` directory.

Answer (score 0):

use 'gulp serve' instead of  'gulp server'

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.